# run configure to generate shared libraries [Ubuntu]

Tags: libraries, dynamic-linking, c++

I'm running a ./configure script and make to build a library. However, only .a libraries are generated. Is there an option to generate shared libs?

Comment: What configure script? Which library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's going to depend on the project you're trying to build. Run

```
./configure --help
```

to get a list of all options you can pass to `./configure`, there may be a `--shared` option or something similar.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that there is an enable-shared option. But for some reason, it is generating static libraries only, and not dynamic libraries.

Comment: @Bob if you can [edit] your question to include more details about exactly which library you're trying to build we can get a better idea of what the issue is. After running `./configure --enable-shared`, have you gone through the `Makefile` to see if there's a shared option, and to ensure that it's set?